# Hide cells in InAppSettingsKit dynamically (target oriented)

Tags: objective-c, inappsettingskit

I have two targets (let's say lite and pro) in my project and I want to change the content of settings according to the target. Is it possible to do that? Can I hide some cells from code? Thanks...

Answer (score 6):

Anyway, I found it!

```c
#ifdef PRO_VERSION       
    controller.hiddenKeys = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Key1", @"Key2", nil];
#endif
```

So in the "pro" version of the app, Key1 and Key2 cells are hidden.